# Nested if statements vs &&(or) operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement

I've been trying to solve this https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/profile-lookup/ with the following code:

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
for (let a = 0; a < contacts.length; a++) {
  if (contacts[a].firstName == name && contacts[a].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    console.log(contacts[a][prop]);
  }
    else if (name != contacts[a].firstName) {
      return "No such contact";
    }
     else {
       return "No such property";
     }
}
```

However this page https://guide.freecodecamp.org/certifications/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/profile-lookup proposes the following, and it works:

```
for (var x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++){
if (contacts[x].firstName === name) {
    if (contacts[x].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[x][prop];
    } else {
        return "No such property";
    }
}
}
return "No such contact";
```

I also tried modifying the above to this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++) {
    if (contacts[x].firstName === name && contacts[x].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            return contacts[x][prop];
        } else {
            return "No such property";
        }
    }
}
return "No such contact";
```

To no avail, though.
So my question is, why doesn't my code work? And why is there the need to use nested if statements instead of && operator?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You should check https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the function that you created will always return: `contacts[x][prop];` or `"No such property"`, and, this line `return "No such contact";` will never be executed, **Why ?**

By nesting the two `if` statements, the new `if` statement that will fall in returning either: `contacts[x][prop];` if it validates to `true` or `"No such property"` if it validates to `false` and thus this line will no longer be executed/accessible, even if the `contacts[x].firstName === name` condition validates to `false`. And that's why two `if` statements are used: the first to return `"No such contact";` if it is `false` (even without an `else` statement, because nothing will be executed in the first `if` statement, if it validates to `false` of course, and thus, the function jumps to the next line after that `if` statement which is `return "No such contact";`)

**Simply:** your function will return `"No such property"` even if the `contacts[x].firstName === name` is `falsy`.

Here's a snippet to illustrate:

```js
// some dummy values just for the demo !
var contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "ths",
    lastName: "sakh"
  },
  {
    firstName: "firstname",
    lastName: "lastname"
  }
];

/**
* The modified function
**/

var r = (function test(name, prop) {
for (var x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++) {
    if (contacts[x].firstName === name && contacts[x].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            return contacts[x][prop];
        } else {
            return "No such property";
        }
    }
  return "No such contact";
})("Wrong Name!", "firstName");
console.log('The modified function returned: "' + r + '" instead of return "No such contact"');

/**
* The original function
**/

var r = (function test(name, prop) {
  for (var x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++){
    if (contacts[x].firstName === name) {
      if (contacts[x].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[x][prop];
      } else {
         return "No such property";
      }
    }
  }
  return "No such contact";
})("Wrong Name!", "firstName");
console.log('The original function returned: "' + r + '" and that\'s what should be returned.');
```

Hope I pushed you further.

*Ps: don't panic by the syntax `var r = (function(x, y){...}(arg1, arg2)` that's an `IIFE` (aka `(Immediately Invoked Function Expression)`). [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Glossaire/IIFE) about it.*

Answer (score 0):

Each function you have posted has a unique behavior. The difference in the last two functions is that when you have `contacts`, in your modified `function`, if the expression you are testing with your `if` statement evaluates to `false`, `"No such property"` will be returned and you will only return `"No such contact"` in the case of having no `contacts` only.

Answer (score 0):

If the input of the function is "Harry" who happens to be in the second or third place of the object, the loop won't reach because on the first iteration it will go to "No such contact" and stop running the function!